# How to adapt images with CardView?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-widget, android-cardview

I am creating an App Gallery using CardView as my widget, but I am facing a problem that the images in my gallery are ignoring the size that I want for them, so they are all overlapping instead of creating a margin for it.

I am adapting the following Android Image Gallery:

https://medium.com/@moforemmanuel/android-simple-image-gallery-30c0f00abe64

I want something like that:

[image]

But running my code I get this result when I have more than one image:
[image]

And the code that I have based myself on you can see below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="190dp"
    android:layout_height="190dp">

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft=".5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight=".5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom=".5dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="1dp">

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/image"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:scaleType="center"
                tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

        </FrameLayout>


    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

What should I change in my code so that I can modify the images' size and still maintain a margin so that I will always have an adaptive layout?

Many thanks!

P.S.:
I've tried what Dharmaraj suggested but then I got the following layout:
[image]

Changing `android:layout_width` and `android:layout_height` to `"200sp"`, it stills overlaps as you can see below:

[image]

To load the images I am using this two functions:
[image]

Comment: by overlap do you mean that images are getting cropped??

Comment: Yes, as you can see in the images, they are all getting cropped.

Comment: Thats because we have fixed the value of CardView. Can you try setting the height and width of the CardView equal to the height and width of the image??

Comment: But remember if you adjust the height and width as per the image it might take up a lot of  space on the screen

Comment: In the original code (the one that I added the link in the question), the developer used `android:layout_width="90dp"` and
    `android:layout_height="90dp"`

Comment: Yeah thats for like a preview of image. I am trying to figure it out how here managed to trim size of the photo. I'll try it once and let you know asap.

Answer (score 0):

Try out this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="100sp"
        android:layout_height="100sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="1sp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="1sp"
        android:layout_marginRight="1sp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="1Sp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="1sp">

  <RelativeLayout
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:layout_margin="5sp>

    <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_center="true" />

  </RelativeLayout>
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

I've basically replaced FrameLayout with RelativeLayout for ease and please assign a constant height and width to the card view. Don't assign a constant height and width to the main layout. This fixed this problem for me. Please let me know if you need more clarification in the comments.

By the way the attribute `android:src` in image is missing. Or are you assigning image dynamically?

Comment: It didn't work as I wanted, I tried to change the layout_width and layout_height as well, but the images still overlap. I will update the question so that you can see what happened.

Comment: @Codewraith can you please say how are you adding images to it? I can't see `android:src` there. And are you dynamically trying to create such cardviews for more images?

Comment: I added to the question how I am loading the images.

Comment: If you need you can take a look in the code that I've used as my base, it's basically that one from Medium (I've added the link in the question).

Comment: @Codewraith sure having a look